# Can't assign to literal in Python turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am python beginner and when I type in this code the error says "can't assign to literal" how do I fix this?

```
from turtle import*
from math import*
def triangle(): 
   triangle=(int(bodylength))/5*3/2/cos(70)
   penup()
   forward(int(bodylength)/5)
   pendown()
   left(70)
   forward(int('triangle'))
   right(140)
   forward(int('triangle'))
   forward(int(bodylength)/5)
triangle()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although changing `forward(int('triangle'))` to `forward(int(triangle))` is necessary, it's not sufficient as `bodylength` is undefined.  Let's rework it to get make the code clearer and run:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
import math

def triangle(turtle, bodylength):
    distance = bodylength / 5 * 3 / 2 / math.cos(math.radians(70))
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.forward(bodylength / 5)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.left(70)
    turtle.forward(distance)
    turtle.right(140)
    turtle.forward(distance)
    turtle.forward(bodylength / 5)

screen = Screen()

yertle = Turtle()

triangle(yertle, int(input("Body length: ")))

screen.exitonclick()  # depending on the environment, you may not need this
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your statement `'triangle'=(int(bodylength))/5*3/2/cos(70)`. You can't set a string literal to be equal to something else. If you meant for that to be a variable, you need to remove the quotes from around it. Also, you shouldn't have a variable with the same name as a function.

Comment: *"you shouldn't have a variable with the same name as a function."* You shouldn't, but technically you can

Answer (score 0):

intead of using `'triangle'` use just `triangle`

so your code will look like this:

```
from turtle import*
from math import*
def triangle(): 
   triangle=(int(bodylength))/5*3/2/cos(70)
   penup()
   forward(int(bodylength)/5)
   pendown()
   left(70)
   forward(int(triangle))
   right(140)
   forward(int(triangle))
   forward(int(bodylength)/5)
triangle()
```

You need to do this because `'triangle'` to python is a *String* not a *variable*. To find out more about variables and strings, just google what is the difference between strings and variables

Note: Looks like there may be other errors to your code like `forward()`. You might need to call `turtle.forward()` or something. And I also think that `Math.cos()` takes rad instead of deg for the parameter.

Comment: The `forward()` calls are fine due to the wild card import of turtle.  You're right about the degrees vs. radians issue.  But that only makes the answer wrong,  what keeps the above code from running at all is the undefined `bodylength`.